# Run command via SSH, disconnect, send input to it later?

Tags: linux, ssh

I am interested to know how can I run a process in SSH that accepts user input, then disconnect without interrupting anything (the process still runs), then come back later and "attach" to it and use it again.

I am interested in running a game server on a Pi (with Arch Linux on it) and I want to be able to connect to the Pi every now and then and attach to the server process to be able to send command like "kick (player)" or "stop", etc, via the standard input of that process.

I would also like to run more "simple" processes like calculations that take a long time to complete (school projects) and leave them running on the Pi, but I want to still be able to get the output when they finish, or stop them if I consider they took too long (I guess I'd do that by killing the process, right?).

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a suggestion to use `tmux`.
you can access server then open a `tmux` (tmux is a terminal multiplexer), and do what you want then detached and logout from your ssh session and then ssh again and reattach to the same terminal.
for more info http://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/